# How to read the ROW FORMAT DELIMITED with SEQUENCEFILE in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following Hive table definition:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE english_1grams (
 gram string,
 year int,
 occurrences bigint,
 pages bigint,
 books bigint
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS SEQUENCEFILE
location 's3://datasets.elasticmapreduce/ngrams/books/20090715/eng-all/1gram/';
```

From: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/Elastic-MapReduce/5249664154115844

It works just fine in Hive. However, when trying to use it wirh Spark, it gives an error:

```
Operation not allowed: ROW FORMAT DELIMITED is only compatible with 'textfile', not 'sequencefile'(line 1, pos 0)
```

How can I read this table in Spark SQL? I've removed the `ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'` from the definition but that returns just gibberish instead of the actual data.

Comment: did you find a solution to it?

Comment: @serverliving.com Unfortunately no. You can try to create a new table in Hive, import all data and then export it into a new Hive table, which is compatible with Spark.